# Cyclic system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
x^2+(1-y)^2&=a\\
y^2+(1-z)^2&=b\\
z^2+(1-x)^2&=c\\
\end{align*}
$$
Compute $x(1-x)$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

**Edit:**
The question should say

> Compute *all* possible values of $x(1-x)$ in terms of $a,b,c$

Comment: I can show that $x(1-x)+y(1-y)+z(1-z)=(3-a-b-c)/2$. Is it useful?

Comment: Have you tried using quadratic residues?

Comment: I use the expression $3=(1-x+x)^2+(1-y+y)^2+(1-z+z)^2=2x(1-x)+2y(1-y)+2z(1-z)+a+b+c$

Comment: Use wolfram-alpha?

Comment: I was able to derive that $2(x+y+z) = 0$

Comment: @VarunIyer How can one derive $2(x+y+z)=0$ when any $x,y,z$ may be put in, and then compute $a,b,c$?

Comment: @coffeemath by subtracting equations

Comment: @VarunIyer You must have made an error. Did you keep the $a,b,c$ on the right sides? If so how does a linear combination of the equations wind up with no occurrences of $a,b,c$ in it??

Comment: @pre-kidney -- Did you forget some condition(s) on the constants and/or variables in your statement? Because (see my answer) as it stands one cannot get $x(1-x)$ in terms of $a,b,c.$

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 6):

Let $a,b,c$ be $5/2,5/4,1/4.$ Then there are two solutions of the system giving different values for $x(1-x)$, so that one cannot in general determine it from the equations. The two solutions are $(x,y,z)=(3/2,1/2,0)$ and $(x,y,z)=(1/2,-1/2,0).$ Then note that $x(1-x)$ is $-3/4$ for the first solution, but is $+1/4$ for the second solution.

Perhaps the OP has omitted some conditions, maybe that the variables and/or the constants $a,b,c$ are to be integers. However as stated the problem can't have a solution for arbitrary $a,b,c$ to get $x(1-x)$ in terms of them.

**Added:** Restricting $a,b,c$ to be integers is still not enough to allow computation of $x(1-x)$ from the equations and the values of $a,b,c$. Given integers $m,n$ each of the choices
$$(x,y,z)=(m,\ n+1,\ m+1),\\ (x,y,z)=(-m,\ n+1,\ -m+1)\tag{*}$$
leads to the same values for $a,b,c$ namely
$$(a,b,c)=(m^2+n^2,\ m^2+(n+1)^2,\ 2m^2+2).$$
But the first solution of $(*)$ gives $x(1-x)=m(1-m)=m-m^2,$ while the second solution gives $x(1-x)=-m(1+m)=-m-m^2$ which differs from the first (for any $m \neq 0$).

Comment: How did you find these specific values, could you show us your work? I'm interested as to how you derived these solutions.

Comment: @VishwaIyer I started by putting $x=m,y=n+1$ so the first equation became $m^2+n^2=a.$ Then I thought to make two solutions, keeping the same $n$ but changing sign on $m$ for the other solution. By trial and error I then found a possible $z$ that works. This involved using the idea that one can change sign inside a square and/or switch the order of two squares in any of the equations. I no longer have the details available, but that's the basic approach I used.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, "Given the system,

$$x^2+(1-y)^2 = a\tag1$$

$$y^2+(1-z)^2 =b\tag2$$

$$z^2+(1-x)^2 =c\tag3$$

compute ***all*** possible values of $x(1-x)$ in terms of $a,b,c$."

> **Answer:** In general, there are ***eight*** possible values for $x(1-x)$.

**Proof:** You have three equations in three unknowns $x,y,z$, hence you can resolve this to one equation in one unknown. Eliminate $y$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$ (easily done with *Mathematica's* *Resultant*[] function), then eliminate $z$ between that and $(3)$, and you get the *octic* in $x$,

$$\small \prod \big(c-\big(b-t+(x-1)^2\color{red}+2\sqrt{t}\pm2\sqrt{b-t-1\color{red}+2\sqrt{t}}\big)\big) \\ \small\big(c-\big(b-t+(x-1)^2\color{red}-2\sqrt{t}\pm2\sqrt{b-t-1\color{red}-2\sqrt{t}}\big)\big)\tag4$$

where $t=a-x^2$. Expanding $(4)$, the four sign changes will result in an octic in $x$ with coefficients in $a,b,c$. Since you don't require that it be in radicals, then one can always numerically solve for $x$ for any given $a,b,c$ and, in general, will find eight values for $x(1-x)$.